# Letters as star pattern

Tags: python

I've written these two functions to return a letters 'A' and 'H' as a stars pattern. Is there any way to print them next each other or should I rewrite the code to print them as one pattern?

```
rows = 8
cols = 8
sym = '*'
thick = 2

def A(rows, cols, sym, thick):
    tmp = ''
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if (i == 0 or i == 1) and j != 1 and j != 0:
                tmp += sym
            elif i > 1 and j == 0 or j == cols - 1:
                tmp += sym * thick
            elif i == 3 or i == 4:
                tmp += sym
            else:
                tmp += ' '
        tmp += '\n'
    return tmp

def H(rows, cols, sym, thick):
    tmp = ''
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if j == 0 or j == 7:
                tmp += sym * thick
            if i != 3 and (i != 4):
                tmp += ' '
            elif (i == 3 and j != 7) or (i == 4 and j != 7):
                tmp += sym
        tmp += '\n'
    return tmp


str = H(rows, cols, sym, thick)
str += A(rows, cols, sym, thick)
print(str)
```

The output is:

[image: the output here]

Comment: You have to rewrite them.

Comment: You don't have to rewrite them, you could write a function that iterates over the rows in them, removes the newline character from intermediates, and adds them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 general solutions:

1. Add logic to split the returned strings in to lines, than recombine them
2. Add logic to print the returned strings line by line
3. Use the [pycurses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) module to create a separate window for each character and print them there.

I will demonstrate method #1 here as it is the simplest:

```
#you need this if you plan on letters of different height
from itertools import zip_longest

rows = 8
cols = 8
sym = '*'
thick = 2

def A(rows, cols, sym, thick):
    tmp = ''
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if (i == 0 or i == 1) and j != 1 and j != 0:
                tmp += sym
            elif i > 1 and j == 0 or j == cols - 1:
                tmp += sym * thick
            elif i == 3 or i == 4:
                tmp += sym
            else:
                tmp += ' '
        tmp += '\n'
    return tmp

def H(rows, cols, sym, thick):
    tmp = ''
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if j == 0 or j == 7:
                tmp += sym * thick
            if i != 3 and (i != 4):
                tmp += ' '
            elif (i == 3 and j != 7) or (i == 4 and j != 7):
                tmp += sym
        tmp += '\n'
    return tmp


h = H(rows, cols, sym, thick)
a = A(rows, cols, sym, thick)
s = ""

#if your letters are guaranteed to be same height, you can use regular zip
for line in zip_longest(h.split('\n'), a.split('\n'), fillvalue=''):
    s += line[0] + ' ' + line[1] + '\n'
print(s)
```

Notice I changed your `str` var to `s` because `str` is a built in function in Python and you should not use it for your own variable names!

Also, all lines in "H" except middle to have a space at the end.
This is a bug in your `H` function, but should be easy to fix for you.

Comment: Sounds good thanks sir i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative solution:

```
from operator import add

h = H(rows, cols, sym, thick)
a = A(rows, cols, sym, thick)

# horizontal join
res = '\n'.join(map(add, h.split('\n'), a.split('\n')))
print(res)
```

which yields:

```
**       **   ******
**       **   ******
**       ** **      **
*********************
*********************
**       ** **      **
**       ** **      **
**       ** **      **
```

The inconsistencies in spacing come from the fact, that you add no padding to the H bar.

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful